# extplorer - file permissions with IIS based FTP

Tags: php, iis

I've set up extplorer PHP script on an IIS 7 based server that also has FTP service running. The app works file i.e. connects to the FTP server using local user account and is able to upload files.

However, the files are listed with no read/write permissions (`chmod 0`). Once a file is uploaded, there's no way to delete or modify it. When I try to chmod manually (using extplorer), I get `CHMOD Failure` error message.

I've got `Anonymous Authentication` enabled on the extplorer site in IIS manager, but that doesn't seem to help much.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS FTP provides *zero* ownership/permissions support. Period.

Some third-party FTP server software *might* shoehorn in the functionality, but the fact remains that FTP is based around Unix-style permissions which are wholly incompatible with Windows NTFS-style permissions.